# View location of cursor position in android simulator

Tags: android

I wrote simple program that draws the circle when I catch `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event:

```
case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
   canvas.drawCircle(event.getX() event.getY(), 10, paint);
```

Everything works fine but I would expect that this circle will drawn around my mouse pointer. Actually the circle always drawn aside from the cursor.

Please see the screen capture below:

[image]

Why this happens?

I use Android studio 1.4.1 and Nexus 5 API 21 x86 virtual device (simulator).

This updated code "fix" the problem

```
case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
   canvas.drawCircle(event.getX() event.getY()-70, 10, paint);
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, can you post what happens after enabling 'Show Touches' in Settings>Developer options ?

Comment: The same result after enabling 'Show Touches'